# Retrieve other values of child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Structure]
So, I have this Firebase Structure.

I made an autocompletetext to get all child named "alimento".
That's OK!

But now, based on this "alimento" selection, I want to get all other childs in TextViews referent to this selection.

Is It possible? I don't know If I was clear enough.

This is my code: (I tried a lot of stuff, but all always return 0.00, so I won't put anything)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnList, buttonAdicionar;

    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList);
        buttonAdicionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdicionar);

        //Nothing special, create database reference.
        final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        //Create a new ArrayAdapter with your context and the simple layout for the dropdown menu provided by Android
        final HRArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new HRArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        //Child the root before all the push() keys are found and add a ValueEventListener()
        database.child("alimentos").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                adapter.clear();
                //Basically, this says "For each DataSnapshot *Data* in dataSnapshot, do what's inside the method.
                for (DataSnapshot suggestionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    //Get the suggestion by childing the key of the string you want to get.
                    String autocomplete = suggestionSnapshot.child("alimento").getValue(String.class);

                    adapter.add(autocomplete);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acTV);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);



        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final String alimento = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Log.d("TAG", alimento);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), alimento,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              
            }


        });


        btnList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FoodActivity.class));

            }
        });

        buttonAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewAlimentoActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }

}
```

This is an example that what I want (using SQL):
[image: Example]

Comment: "I tried a lot of stuff, but all always return 0.00" that's not very informative, try to be more specific.

Also, just to make sure the data is being retrieved, inside the for (DataSnapshot suggestionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){ .. }  
put some Logs or a debug breakpoint to check everything is fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to get all child nodes with a specific value in their `alimento` property, that'd be something like:

```
database.child("alimentos")
        .orderByChild("alimento")
        .equalTo("Arroz, integral, cozido")
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String base = snapshot.child("base").getValue(String.class);
            double baseValue = Double.parseDouble(base);
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: OMG. How stupid I am.  I can't vote the answer. 
I just made a change: 
Instead of .equalTo("xxxxx") I put .equalTo(alimento)

Comment: Good to hear it works. Though you can't upvote (yet, you're almost at the required 15 reputation), you will be able to accept the answer once the system allows it (it takes a couple hours iirc).